# How to input an mp3 file into CARTO

Tags: carto, carto-js, representation

I am trying to create a bubble map in CARTO in which a user can click on a bubble and one of the fields that appears is an mp3 file. Alternatively, a soundcloud page with the mp3 could appear with the bubbles' other fields.

My research on the subject has not been fruitful, although I have seen maps that do this successfully: http://www.antievictionmappingproject.net/narratives.html (here the blue bubbles have audio come up when they are clicked).

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect [the web application](http://www.antievictionmappingproject.net/narratives.html) you have shared with us, the authors have used a `<iframe>` tag with the soundclound info within a fixed infowindow (iw). So in order to get the same result you should follow these steps:

1-Create a visualization application with CARTO.js ([documentation](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/carto-js/) and [tutorials](https://carto.com/academy/courses/cartojs-ground-up/)).

2-Secondly, add a (fixed or not) custom iw ([tutorial](https://carto.com/docs/tutorials/custom_interactivity/)).

3-Within the iw `<div>` add a soundcloud `<iframe>` ([documentation](https://soundcloud.com/pages/embed)).